# Not displaying proper output when display() function is called in stack in C

Tags: c, stack

Below is the implementation of a stack data structure using linked list in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
    int data;
    struct stack *next;
};
struct stack *top = NULL;

void push(int d)
{
    struct stack *nptr;
    nptr = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        nptr->data = d;
        nptr->next = NULL;
        top = nptr;
    }
    else
    {
        nptr->data = d;
        nptr->next = top;
        top = nptr;
    }
}
void display()
{
    while (top != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", top->data);
        top = top->next;
    }
}

void pop()
{
    struct stack *temp = top;
    top = top->next;
    free(temp);
}

int main()
{
    push(5);
    push(6);
    push(7);
    pop();     // This works fine
    display(); // This works as well
    pop();     // The element does not pop when called.
    display(); // The stack does not display.
    return 0;
}
```

The final output of the program is:

```
6
5

shell returned -1073741819
```

The actual output of the program should be:

```
6
5
5
```

I couldn't find anything wrong in the program but the output is not as expected. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: pop() returns nothing.  It just pops an item and frees it.  That does not sound useful:(

Comment: You have an extra 'if (top == NULL)' in push and need it in pop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first call to `display()` you destroy your stack.
This is because you manipulate a global variable which should afterwards be unchanged.
Your `pop()` does not check for `NULL` and at the call after `display()` unconditionally dereferences the pointer which indeed is `NULL` because of the misbehaviour of `display()` and not protecting against unexpected `NULL`.

Comment: OK. Really helpful .

Comment: Thanks for your feedback....feeling annoyed for not figuring it on my own something as simple as that

Comment: Do not be too hard on yourself. This is normal "over focusing" on your view on how it works, which sometimes hides how it does not work.